# Adding an integer and string to a list with new lines

Tags: python, string, list, int, rows

I have some code that generates a integer and a str and I can get them to append into a list but I would like them on a seperate line for each int and str. My code is as follows:

```
responses = []
responses.append(respTime)
responses.append(category_repeated)
responses = [0.11700010299682617        correct     0.1000001431        correct     0.0779998302        correct]
```

I would like this so it can be opened into libreOffice calc into rows with two columns:

```
0.117000 correct
0.100000 correct
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I might use nested array and a csv writter to make a file usable with libreoffice.

Comment: Yep. That is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to process if you have a list of tuples:

```
responses = []
responses.append((respTime, category_repeated)) # <--- slight difference
responses == [(0.11700010299682617, 'correct'), (0.1000001431, 'correct')]
# responses[0] == (0.11700010299682617, 'correct')
```

Here is an example for writing a .csv file from the docs:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```